# Loop though object image to change background color

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I'm trying to loop through all the images starts from the 2nd page in an MS Word file and change the background colors to white.

currently, all the Word content is changing the background colors and not only the Images.

How can I loop only the through object image?

My code:

```
Sub RemoveBackgroundColor()
   With ActiveDocument.Content
       .HighlightColorIndex = wdWhite
       .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorWhite
   End With
   ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
End Sub
```

Comment: `I'm trying to loop through all the images starts from the 2nd page in an MS Word file and change the background colors to white.` I do not see any code where you are removing the background of any image?

Comment: `.HighlightColorIndex = wdWhite`

Comment: It does changes the background color but also for tables and not only for Images.

Comment: no but you are not doing that for image. you are doing that for word document

Comment: you're right, that was what I manage to do and now I would like to be more accurate and run the code only for image objects :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to loop through all the document and check whether the obj is an image or not. if it is an image then I will apply the code.

Comment: You need to loop through `.InlineShapes` and check if `Type = wdInlineShapePicture`. Also what do you mean by changing the background? Fill the shape? create a border around it?

Comment: I want to remove the black background of a PNG picture. I saw it's a known issue and can be fixed with a macro. that might help me: `.TransparentBackground = msoTrue`

Comment: @TimothyRylatt so in this case recording a macro might not help me?

Comment: `I want to remove the black background of a PNG picture. I saw it's a known issue and can be fixed with a macro. that might help me: .TransparentBackground = msoTrue – User1 6 mins ago` Well, if [THIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/remove-the-background-of-a-picture-c0819a62-6844-4190-8d67-6fb1713a12bf) is what you are trying to achieve then if I am not wrong then you cannot do that in VBA as the code will not understand what is a background and what is a foreground. You will have to do it manually.

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes this is the case and it works. BUT for the all document and not only for pictures.